# Browser downloads source code from server when I access my site through https

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx

I'm running nginx on an ubuntu computer.  I've just created an ssl certificate and configured it in the available-sites file as follows:

```
server {

        listen 443;
        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www;
        index index.php;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.key;
}
```

when I goto https://[address] my browser downloads the website's source code and it doesn't display anything in the browser.  If I comment out the `root` line in the config file the browser displays the 'Welcome to Nginx' page.

How can I get the browser to display my site when I access it from https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an nginx and php-fpm set up, you need to have nginx forward requests for any files ending in `.php` to the php processor.

Specifically, you seem to be missing this `location` block inside of your `server` block:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /path/to/your/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/your/web/root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```